# Grunt build puts bootstrap fonts in wrong directory

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-compass

I have an AngularJS project that I'm attempting to build.  Everything works, except that the fonts in the vendor.css are not correct.

```
Example:  url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff)
```

Obviously this causes a 404:

> Request
>   URL:`http://localhost:8000/public/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:404 Not Found

I want the vendor css file to be generated with the correct address for the fonts.  Can anyone tell me what I need to change in my Grunt or index file(s)?

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>


// Generated on 2014-06-20 using generator-angular 0.7.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            },
            karma: {
                files: ['test/unit/*.js','app/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['karma:unit']
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ],
            test: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
                },
                src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: [
                            '.tmp',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                        src: '{,*/}*.css',
                        dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        'bowerInstall': {
            app: {
                src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
            }
        },


        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/sass',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false,
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
                        src: '{,*/}*.html',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/components'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/main',
                        src: '{,*/}*.html',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/main'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
        // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                        src: '*.js',
                        dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        src: [
                            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                            '.htaccess',
                            '*.html',
                            'main/{,*/}*.html',
                            'bower_components/**/*',
                            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                            'fonts/*'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/images',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                        src: ['generated/*']
                    }
                ]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass:server'
            ],
            test: [
                'compass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'compass:dist',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //   dist: {}
        // },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                autoWatch: true,
                singleRun: true
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'bowerInstall',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'bowerInstall',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngmin',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old Angular Generator (it looks like 0.7.1), and the issue you might be having been fixed in recent versions (at least as of 0.9.5). Update your Angular generator (you can just type `yo` and select the `Update your generators` option) and then re-generate your app.

You might want to look at [References to font (font-awesome) resources are not updated in yeoman/angular grunt build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893778/references-to-font-font-awesome-resources-are-not-updated-in-yeoman-angular-gr) as well.

If that doesn't fix it, it'd be useful to see your `main.css` file.